Prove a determinant $= \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!} \prod_{i > j} (x_i - x_j)$.
Let $ a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b $ , f  is continuous on the interval $[a, b]$ and has $n$th continuous derivatives on $(a, b)$. Prove that there exists $\xi \in (a, b)$ such that the following determinant holds:
$$ \left|\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\ x_0 & x_1 & \ldots & x_n \\ x_0^2 & x_1^2 & \ldots & x_n^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \ldots & x_n^{n-1} \\ f(x_0) & f(x_1) & \ldots & f(x_n) \end{array}\right| = \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!} \prod_{i > j} (x_i - x_j) $$
I think this is related to the Lagrange interpolation remainder, where the Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial is
$$
L_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n y_k l_k(x),\quad l_k(x)=\frac{\left(x-x_0\right) \cdots\left(x-x_{k-1}\right)\left(x-x_{k+1}\right) \cdots\left(x-x_n\right)}{\left(x_k-x_0\right) \cdots\left(x_k-x_{k-1}\right)\left(x_k-x_{k+1} \cdots\left(x_k-x_n\right)\right.}, k=0,1, \cdots, n$$
Let $\omega_{n+1}(x)=\left(x-x_0\right)\left(x-x_1\right) \cdots\left(x-x_n\right)$,then
$$
R_n(x)=f(x)-L_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} \omega_{n+1}(x),
$$
But I have two problems with this approach. First, the expression to be proved involves the $n$th derivative, but the interpolation remainder is of order $n+1$. Second, I don’t know how to obtain the polynomial part at the end. I tried to expand the determinant along the last row, but I don’t know how to proceed with the subsequent calculations.
Can someone give me some tips or references? Thank you very much!

An observation: for $n=1$ this is just the Mean Value Theorem (a consequence of Rolle's theorem). I haven't checked the details but it is likely that your statement is something like Lemma 3 from this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4935474/633714

@richrow: You are right: Expanding the determinant on the left and dividing it by the product on the right transforms the equation exactly to your “Lemma 3.”

Consider the function $g: (a, b) \to \Bbb R$,
$$
g(x) = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
x & x_0 & x_1 & \ldots & x_n \\ 
x^2 & x_0^2 & x_1^2 & \ldots & x_n^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x^{n-1} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \ldots & x_n^{n-1} \\ 
x^{n} & x_0^{n} & x_1^{n} & \ldots & x_n^{n} \\ 
f(x) & f(x_0) & f(x_1) & \ldots & f(x_n) \end{vmatrix} \, .
$$
Then
$$
 g(x_0) = g(x_1) = \ldots = g(x_n) = 0
$$
and repeated application of Rolle's theorem shows that $g^{(n)}(\xi) = 0$ for some $\xi \in (a, b)$.
Since only the entries in the first column depend on $x$, derivatives of $g$ are simply obtained by differentiating all entries in the first column. In particular is
$$
0 = g^{(n)}(\xi) = \begin{vmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
0 & x_0 & x_1 & \ldots & x_n \\ 
0 & x_0^2 & x_1^2 & \ldots & x_n^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \ldots & x_n^{n-1} \\ 
n! & x_0^{n} & x_1^{n} & \ldots & x_n^{n} \\ 
f^{(n)}(\xi) & f(x_0) & f(x_1) & \ldots & f(x_n) \end{vmatrix} \, .
$$
Expanding this determinant along the first column gives the desired result.

Let $V(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ denote the Vandermonde matrix of $x_0, \ldots, x_n$. Expanding the determinant along the last row gives
$$ \begin{align}
 &\frac{1}{\prod_{1 \le j < i \le n} (x_i - x_j)} \cdot
\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\ x_0 & x_1 & \ldots & x_n \\ x_0^2 & x_1^2 & \ldots & x_n^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \ldots & x_n^{n-1} \\ f(x_0) & f(x_1) & \ldots & f(x_n) \end{vmatrix} \\
&\quad= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} f(x_k) \frac{\det V(x_0, \ldots, x_{k-1}, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_n)}{\det V(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n)} \\
&\quad= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} f(x_k) \frac{1}{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x_k-x_i) \cdot \prod_{j=k+1}^n (x_j-x_k)} \\
&\quad= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f(x_k)}{\prod_{i=0 , i \ne k}^n(x_k - x_i)} \, .
\end{align}
$$
So what we want to show is that
$$ \tag{$*$}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f(x_k)}{\prod_{i=0 , i \ne k}^n(x_k - x_i)}
= \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}
$$
for some $\xi \in (a, b)$. That is Lemma 3 in richrow's answer to Is $\sum_{\substack{n_1+\ldots+n_k=2m\\ n_1,\ldots,n_k\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}}}x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_k^{n_k} \geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^k$?. I'll add a proof here to make the answer self-contained.
Let $P$ be the polynomial of degree at most $n$ which interpolates $f$ at the $(n+1)$ points $x_0, \ldots, x_n$, that is
$$
 P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n f(x_k)  \frac{\prod_{i=0 , i \ne k}^n (x-x_i)}{\prod_{i=0 , i \ne k}^n (x_k-x_i)} \, .
$$
Then $f(x)-P(x) = 0$ for $x=x_0, \ldots, x_k$, and repeated application of Rolle's theorem shows that $f^{(n)}(\xi) - P^{(n)}(\xi) = 0$ for some $\xi \in (a, b)$. It follows that
$$
 f^{(n)}(\xi) = P^{(n)}(\xi) = \sum_{k=0}^n f(x_k)  \frac{n!}{\prod_{i=0 , i \ne k}^n (x_k-x_i)} \, ,
$$
and that is $(*)$.
